# How to maintain parallel dev branches and frequently pull from and push to master?

Tags: git, version-control, git-flow

We have a `master` branch and each developer has his own dev branch(not feature branch) for example `dev-john`, `dev-rahul` etc

Now john takes frequent pulls from `master` to `dev-john` and makes frequent commits to `dev-john`

He occasionally merges his commits on `dev-john` into `master` without closing `dev-john`

I need a git flow where all commits after the last merge are merged into `master` as a single commit with a commit message

I have tried to explain what I need in the graphic below
[image]

could anyone advise the git commands to run at every stage of this flow

flow modify suggestions are also welcome

Comment: If you want to squash the commits on master branch, how do you want to deal with the commits on dev-rahul and dev-john? Since the commits to be squashed on master branch contains merge commit, then the second parent branch for merging will also be effected.

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT commits on `dev-rahul` and `dev-john` are normal commits pushed by the respective developers, once they are done with a feature and made their last commit to the dev branch, all those commits after the last merge to master need to be squash merged into master to keep history clean

Comment: So is it ok for you to delete `dev-rahul` and `dev-john` branches before squashing `master` branch and re-create `dev-rahul` and `dev-john` branches after squashing `master` branch?

Comment: No that's the point. I don't want to delete branches

Comment: I added the answer to squash commits on master branch while keeping the commit history on `dev-rahul` and `dev-john` branches. And you can have a try.

Comment: @Rahul, Not get your response, do you get any latest information in your side?

Answer (score 1):

Assume the commit history for now looks like (`M`x for the merged commits, `R`x commits are the common commits on `dev-rahul` branch, `D`x commits are the common commits on `master` branch, `J`x commits are the common commits on `dev-john` branch):

```
…--------R1--------M3---R2---R3---R4---R5      dev-rahul
           \      /                     \
…------D1---M2---D2--------M4---D3-------M6    master
        \                 /      \
…---J3---M1---J4---J5---J6--------M5           dev-john
```

Then you can use below commands to squash the commits after (squash commits `M4`, `D3` and `M6` into one commit, as the commit `S` in below graph):

```
git checkout master
git reset --soft HEAD~3
git commit -m 'squash commit S for commits M4, D3 and M6'
```

And the commit history will be:

```
 …--------R1--------M3---R2---R3---R4---R5    dev-rahul
           \      /                     
…------D1---M2---D2------S                   master
        \              \
         |              M4---D3    
         |              |      \
…---J3---M1---J4---J5---J6------M5           dev-john
```